# I wrote this program to reverse the elements in a linked list, after compiling this program this is showing error in the reverse (). why?

Tags: c++

I wrote this program to reverse the elements in a linked list, after compiling this program this is showing error in the reverse (). why?

error showing :- 
||In function ‘void reverse()’:|
|40|error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Node’ and ‘long int’)|
|40|note: candidate is:|

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
Node* head;
void insert(int data)
{
   Node* newNode = new Node();    // create a new node
   newNode->data = data;
   newNode->next = NULL;

   if(head == NULL ){   //if head is null, that means this is your first node
      head = newNode;   //so update the value of head
   }else{
      Node* temp = head;
     while(temp->next!=NULL)
     {
        temp = temp->next;
     }
     temp->next = newNode;
   }
 }
void print()
{
    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<" "<<temp->data<<" ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
void reverse()
{
    Node* current;
    Node* prev;
    Node* nextaddress;
    current = head;
    prev = NULL;
    while(current!=NULL)
    {
        nextaddress = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = nextaddress;
    }
    head = prev;
}
int main()
{
    head = NULL;
    int a, n;
    cout<<"\n enter the number of elements to be stored into the list :";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"\n enter those elements :";
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cin>>a;
        insert(a);
    }
    print();
    cout<<"\n the reverse of the linkedlist is :";
    reverse();
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you actually *read* the error messages? Did you check the lines the errors are on? More importantly, you do know that e.g. `Node* current , prev, nextaddress;` only defclares `current` as a pointer, not the other two variables?

Comment: The question could certainly be cleaned up a bit, but it's a legitimate programming mistake for someone who is learning.  I don't agree that closing is appropriate here.

Answer (score 6):

This is why every coding standard says one variable per line.

What you wrote:

```
Node* current , prev, nextaddress;
current = head;
prev = NULL;
```

What you meant was:

```
Node* current , * prev, * nextaddress;
            //  ^^      ^^ Without the star they are Node objects.
current = head;
prev = NULL;
```

What you should have typed was:

```
Node* current      = head;
Node* prev         = nullptr;
Node* nextaddress;
```

Hey look it does not take up any more space.

Answer (score 1):

In C/C++, you need to put a `*` before each variable name that is a pointer.  So in `reverse()` the first line should read:

`Node* current, *prev, *nextaddress; // prev and nextaddress become Node *`